# Capifony: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano, capifony

I am trying to get Capifony working in my Symfony2 application and for the life of me I can't get it working as I don't really know how to debug ruby. Here is what I am doing:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
2.0.3
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

capifony (2.2.8)
capistrano (2.15.4, 2.14.2)
capistrano-maintenance (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
colored (1.2)
highline (1.6.18)
inifile (2.0.2)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)

$ capifony .
[add] writing './Capfile'
[add] writing './app/config/deploy.rb'
[done] symfony 2 project capifonied!

$ cap deploy
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval': deploy:3: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
php app/console assets:install web
                       ^
deploy:4: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console cache:clear
                      ^
deploy:5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
                      ^
deploy:5: syntax error, unexpected tUMINUS, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
                                        ^
deploy:7: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console assetic:dump
                        ^
deploy:8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
                        ^
deploy:8: syntax error, unexpected tUMINUS, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
                                         ^
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
        from Capfile:1:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

I realize I did not touch `deploy.rb` but that is because I get the same errors no matter what I do. Any ideas? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I uninstalled ruby and all gems and then installed ruby 1.8.7 using rvm and reinstalled capifony. I suppose capifony is currently incompatible with the 1.9.* branch of ruby.